# Covariance, Mean of Y

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance, means

Let the number X be chosen at random from among 1,2,3,4 and the number Y be chosen from among those atleast as large as X. Prove that Cov(X,Y) = 5/8.

My attempt:
I have calculated P(X=k) which is equal to 1/4.
And conditional probability, P(Y|X=x), x=1,2,3,4.
Hence, I have calculated P(X=x, Y=y). But my calculation is not yielding Cov(X,Y)= 5/8.

I don't know where the mistake is. But I suspect it's in calculating the mean of Y. How to calculate mean of Y?

It will be helpful if you share the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to derive the joint pmf with a contingency table like the following

[image]

then calculate cov by its definition

$$\mathbb{Cov}[X,Y]=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y]=8.75-2.5\times3.25=0.625=5/8$$

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks @tommik. Btw, there's a mistake in the covariance formula.  Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y). I guess it was a typing mistake 

Comment: @Learner : yes, of course! amended (thanks for your comment)